# Telegram WEB APP (using aiogram) replaces the https protocol with http

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram

Here is a piece of code

```
    keyboard = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    token_api = create_token_api(id)
    web_app_url = Web App Info(url=f"https://<link>?telebot=true&token={token_api}")
    keyboard.add(Keyboard Button(text="test", web_app=web_app_url))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHSdY.png)

At the same time, I am sending this button to the user. Everything would be fine if it weren't for the error that telegram WEB gives out. I have tried different methods and ways to change the transmission of the link and the link itself, deleted the parameters, etc.

I also tried with other links, it works there every other time, that is, it did not replace some https links, and it replaced some. I use the aiogram library by adding the ReplyKeyboardMarkup method to it

Maybe someone has faced such a problem?
P.S. And yes, I am sure that the https protocol is used. but for some reason, the bot replaces it with http

Comment: It is not clear what this code is about: Python or Android? `ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED` can be seen on Android devices

Question lacks context/wide description

Comment: This is python, via the Web app telegram api, https://core.telegram.org/bots/webapps
This error appears on devices when trying to open a link